# Execute multiple *.dat files from subdirectories (bash, python)

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-3.x, subdirectory

I have the following:

1. I have directory with subdirectories which are filled with files. The structure is the following: `/periodic_table/{Element}_lj_dat/lj_dat_sim.dat`;
2. Each file consists of two rows (first one is the comment) and 12 columns of data.
3. What I would like to get is to go through all folders of elements (eg. Al, Cu etc.), open created file (for example named "mergedlj.dat" in `periodic_table` directory) and store all the data from each file in one adding Element name from parent directory as a first (or last) column of merged file.

The best way is to ignore the first row in each file and save only data from second row.

I am very unexperienced in bash/shell scripting, but I think this is the best way to go (Python is acceptable too!). Unfortunately I had only experience with files which are in the same folder as the script, so this is some new experience for me.

Here is the code just to find this files, but actually it doesn't do anything what I need:

```
find ../periodic_table/*_lj_dat/ -name lj_dat_sim.dat -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do 
    echo "Processing $file"
done
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Look at the `os` module of python. It can `walk` you through a directory tree nicely.

Comment: Yeah, I have an idea about python realisation, but I thought that bash should be easy (shorter)... Anyway thanks, if I will do it in Python I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Python solution.

You can use [`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to get a list of the matching files and then iterate over them with [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input). `fileinput.filename()` lets you get the name of the file that is currently being processed, and this can be used to determine the current element whenever processing begins on a new file, as determined by `fileinput.isfirstline()`.

The current element is added as the first column of the merge file. I've assumed that the field separator in the input files is a single space, but you can change that by altering `' '.join()` below.

```
import re
import fileinput
from glob import glob

dir_prefix = '.'
glob_pattern = '{}/periodic_table/*_lj_dat/lj_dat_sim.dat'.format(dir_prefix)
element_pattern = re.compile(r'.*periodic_table/(.+)_lj_dat/lj_dat_sim.dat')

with open('mergedlj.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    element = ''
    for line in fileinput.input(glob(glob_pattern)):
        if fileinput.isfirstline():
            # extract the element name from the file name
            element = element_pattern.match(fileinput.filename()).groups()[0]
        else:
            print(' '.join([element, line]), end='', file=outfile)
```

You can use `os.path.join()` to construct the glob and element regex patterns, but I've omitted that above to avoid cluttering up the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked, but I changed the following: `glob_pattern =  '{}/*_lj_dat/lj_dat_sim.dat'.format(dir_prefix)` and `element_pattern = re.compile(r'(.+)_lj_dat/lj_dat_sim.dat'`

Comment: Because the code was looped as long as I put the code file in the "periodic_table" directory itself. Thanks again!